# VueJs logical conditons with array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array in my data function, and I want to compute the sum of numbers that have a false record in the array. But I need to do it in the computed section but I'm having trouble with the condition on calculating just the false arrays. How would one set up the logical parameter.

```
Array1: [
                {Text1: "Some text in an array 1", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: true},
                {Text2: "Some text in an array 2", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: true},
                {Text3: "Some text in an array 3", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: true},
                {Text4: "Some text in an array 4", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: true},
                {Text5: "Some text in an array 5", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: true},
                {Text6: "Some text in an array 6", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: false},
                {Text7: "Some text in an array 7", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: false},
                {Text10: "Some text in an array 8", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: false},
                {Text8: "Some text in an array 9", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: false},
                {Text9: "Some text in an array 10", Numbers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50), B1: false},
            ],
            sum: 0
computed:{
    sumOfNumbers(){
        return this.Array1.reduce((sum, numbers) =>{
            return sum += numbers.Numbers;
        }, 0)
    },
    sumOfFalse(){
        if(Array1[iii].B1 = 'false'){
            return this.Array1.reduce((sum, numbers) =>{
                return sum += numbers.Numbers;
            }, 0)
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all array items that have a falsy `B1` value, use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const falsyB1Items = this.Array1.filter(item => !item.B1)
```

Then you could reduce those items:

```js
return falsyB1Items.reduce((sum, numbers) => sum += numbers.Numbers, 0)
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mdRMJRb)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just by one function like this:

```
computed: {
    sumOfNumbers() {
        this.Array1.map(obj => {
            if (obj.B1 === false) {
                this.sum += obj.Numbers; // The sum is stored in the 'sum' var
            }
        });
        return this.sum;
    }
}
```

Does it works the way you want?